# Is this solderable?

Tags: arduino, soldering

I have an Arduino Mega and one of the capacitors is broken off. It's the same as the one still attached (47, 25V, RVI) and the capacitor should be placed at location PC2.

I think this is SMD technique, anyway. My soldering skills are not high, I was wondering if I can solder it... since if it's positions at the right location I cannot put my soldering iron to it anymore, also since I don't think I can make the solder overlap the lines coming from the capacitor.

If not possible, would it be an idea to carefully try to solder two wires on the Mega at the connector points of PC2 and use 2 wires which I solder against the capacitor and put the capacitor somewhere else?

[image]

Update:

Does anybody know what would be the consequence to leave the capacitor out completely (like now)? (I did not dare to turn the Arduino Mega on because of the broken capacitor).

Comment: Before you resort to splicing in wires, note that you could just remove the plastic base and have more exposed lead to work with.  This type of "surface mount" components is almost just a through hole one with a little factory adapter included.  That said, beware that if you build an unsecured 3d "sculpture" future damage that may rip even more trace off the board may be a concern.

Comment: note that adding some length of wire might defeat the purpose of having a capacitor at all (since power supply filtering is best if done close to the electronics). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A bit of hot glue after soldering should hold it in place pretty well.  One should take care if using alcohol for cleaning though since it'll cause the glue to unstick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is solderable.  It is not difficult.

You need a soldering iron with a small point, and you need fine solder.  I use 0.5 mm solder for just about everything.

Use solder wick to clean both pads and make them nice and flat.

Use your iron to heat one pad, and melt some solder on that pad.

Place the capacitor so the it sits properly.  Pay attention to the polarity.  This is an electrolytic capacitor. If you connect it backwards it will not work correctly.

Hold the capacitor in place with a pair of tweezers.  Just push down on the top of the capacitor with the tweezers.  This will keep it in place.

Heat the pad that you put solder on.  It will melt, and the capacitor will pop down onto the pad - you can actually feel a "snap" through the tweezers when the capacitor seats.

Remove the iron.  Let the solder cool.  Remove the tweezers.

Apply the iron to the junction of the pad and pin on the unsoldered pin.  Heat them both.

Apply solder to the heated pad and pin.  It will melt and flow to cover both.

Remove the solder, them remove the iron.

Let cool, then resolder the first pad.  The first pad wasn't soldered well because there wasn't enough flux on it.  Heat the junction with the iron until the solder melts.  Apply solder to the junction.  Remove the solder, remove the iron, let cool.

Finished.

This method can be applied to any SMD part with two pads.  More pads can be done just as easily, but you have pay more attention to the alignment.

---

Had a closer look at the picture.  There is a piece of copper stuck to one pin of the capacitor, and a torn place on one of the pads.

You'll have to remove the scrap of copper from the capacitor.

You can solder it back in, no problem.  The rest of the pad appears to still be connected to the ground plane, so when you solder the capacitor to what is left of the pad you will still have a good connection to ground for it.

Comment: Unless one has several hundred dollar soldering iron rather than the basic temperature controlled variety, soldering a component such as this to what are likely heavy power traces is best done with the largest iron tip that can fit.  Using too small a tip will be an exercise in frustration due to poor heat transfer.

Comment: I just replaced two TVSs last night with large ground connections using the above method - no problem.  I have a cheap jack soldering that I bought at a hardware store.  It is temperature controlled, but only 30W.  Besides, the ground pads on this (Arduino) board has thermal reliefs, which will make it easier to work with.

Comment: The thermal relief is part of what caused the failure.  Generally, too small a tip causes more problems than too large.  That would especially be true if any of the solder mask on the groundplace is removed to give an alternate to the broken pad.

Comment: Thanks ... I think I will try this (or maybe even check if it works as is, like the solution of nickagian).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it by hand. As you can see, the pin isn't under the package so it makes things easier to do. If you want to do it yourself, I recommend you to use a soldering iron with a thin head, this will prevent any damage to nearby component.

The solution you submit makes sense but I not sure there is free space left on your board to solder the component.

If your soldering skill are not that high, you rather ask someone to do it for you. Since it's not hard to do, you can ask someone with "correct" skill. I'm thinking of a electronic shop keeper for exemple. If you ask him nicely, he probably do it for free

Comment: I can ask (although it seemed the capacitor is not used in all cases and I can do without, at least for my near future purposes).

Answer (score 5):

This kind of package is normally solderable by hand. But admittedly not the easiest one, especially if, as you said, your soldering skills are not so high!

The trick you mention with the wires is definitely possible, but be careful not to make any short circuit! The voltage across the two pins is most probably the input voltage of the board.

But I think the best idea is to just leave it like this, if you cannot solder it on the board. The effect of this capacitor missing will not be catastrophic for the board operation.

**UPDATE:**
It proved out this last idea of mine was probably not the best one. By checking the schematics of the board, this PC2 that is missing is **required** for the stability of the LDO that produces the 5V power supply of the board. So, operating it without this capacitor is perhaps not the best idea, since the output may be unstable (oscillate) when load transients are present.

Comment: Although I have accepted someone else answer (since it's the 'proper solution'), I will first check if it works without the capacitor.

Comment: can you maybe write what would be the consequences of leaving the capacitor out?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I will need to have a look at the schematics of the board (which I don't have) to tell you with more confidence. But my best guess is that it is a bulk capacitor that smooths the fluctuations of the power supply input voltage that is provided from that black barrel connector. But I don't know if there is another regulator on-board. In general, when we put capacitors on a board we usually have good reasons for them, but these may not be so obvious to the user (e.g. EMC reasons). What I'm trying to say: most probably you will not notice a thing with this capacitor missing.

Comment: I will try it without any fix to see if it does 'startup' (I will not blame you if there will be smoke) :-)

Comment: The schematics can be found at http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/file/view/arduino-mega2560-schematic-F.jpg/346627792/arduino-mega2560-schematic-F.jpg  ... in the left upper part, PC2 is mentioned. But for me it's still not possible to see the real 'use'.

Comment: The 'blink' example works (meaning it can turn in internal test led on/off), and uploading a sketch it works :-)

Comment: In another answer someone said it would be ONLY when using the Vin or Barrel input, but works ok for USB ... which is also fine. But still thanks for sorting out (knowing if I need stability I would have to fix it).

Comment: Well from the schematics, this is definitely true. This LDO and the PC2 are only relevant if you supply the board from the barrel input. It is irrelevant with the USB power supply, since USB already supplies the 5V.

Comment: So now I have a Mega for 'trying this' with USB (which is good enough for me). I get a replacement for the broken Arduino Mega anyway :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is actually quite easy to do with a ordinary soldering iron.  However, there are two problems in your specific case you need to address:

The top pad in the picture may have been partially lifted and part of the copper torn off.  The bottom part of the SMD pad being dark indicates something is not right.  Maybe the part was not soldered down well in the first place, and this is just flux residue where there wasn't solder contact.

In any case, put some fresh solder on that pad and see if you can make it flow over the whole pad.  If you can, then there is probably no problem.  However, inspect the pad carefully to see if there is a connection to a trace from the dark area, and that this connection is unbroken.

It looks like part of the lead of the cap tore off from the cap and is left on the bottom pad.  That's better than the other case since the pad is most likely OK, and you're not going to re-use the broken-off cap anyway.

Put more solder on this pad, then remove the metal piece by pushing it away once the solder is flowing nicely.

To solder on the replacement cap:

In any case, put some solder on both pads, make sure it flows well and covers the whole pad, then clean off the pads with a solder wick.

Put a little solder on one of the pads only.  I'd pick the bottom one since it's easier to get at it with a soldering iron when the cap is in place.

Hold the cap in place and melt the little bit of solder you put on the pad.  Make sure it flows.

Let it cool to harden.  This will hold the cap in place.

Apply heat and solder to the other pad.  Make sure it flows and makes a good connection.

Go back to the first pad and re-flow the solder.  Add a little to make sure the connection is properly wetted if you're not sure.